# Programming a function for "lm" using tidyeval

Tags: r, lm, tidyeval

I am trying to write a function around "lm" using tidyeval (non-standard evaluation).Using base R NSE, it works:

```
lm_poly_raw <- function(df, y, x, degree = 1, ...){
  lm_formula <-
    substitute(expr = y ~ poly(x, degree, raw = TRUE),
               env = list(y = substitute(y),
                          x = substitute(x),
                          degree = degree))
  eval(lm(lm_formula, data = df, ...))
}

lm_poly_raw(mtcars, hp, mpg, degree = 2)
```

However, I have not figured out how to write this function using `tidyeval` and `rlang`. I assume that `substitute` should be replaced be `enquo`, and eval by `!!`. There are some hints in Hadley's Adv-R, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In Order to program with the dplyr functions, it ist useful to usw tidyeval/rlang, and I simply would like to use one system. Beides, I would like to explain to some Studenten nse, and I think using one system only ist easier, more consistent.

Comment: Given lm() does not use the same form of NSE as dplyr, I don't think hitting it with rlang will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the kind of formula constructor that might make its way in rlang in the future:

```
f <- function(x, y, flatten = TRUE) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)

  # Environments should be the same
  # They could be different if forwarded through dots
  env <- get_env(x)
  stopifnot(identical(env, get_env(y)))

  # Flatten the quosures. This warns the user if nested quosures are
  # found. Those are not supported by functions like lm()
  if (flatten) {
    x <- quo_expr(x, warn = TRUE)
    y <- quo_expr(y, warn = TRUE)
  }

  new_formula(x, y, env = env)
}

# This can be used for unquoting symbols
var <- "cyl"
lm(f(disp, am + (!! sym(var))), data = mtcars)
```

The tricky parts are:

- The LHS and RHS could come from different environments if forwarded through different layers of `...`. We need to check for this.
- We need to check that the user doesn't unquote quosures. `lm()` and co do not support those. `quo_expr()` flattens all the quosures and optionally warns if some were found.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Still need to wrap my head around it though :)